# Get County and State using zip code (reverze_zipcode)

Tags: r, dataframe, zipcode, zipcoder

I have a list of unique client names and their zip codes.

I need to get extra information regarding the zip code such as state and county.

I discovered the package **zipcodeR** but **wasn't able to use the reverse_zipcode function**.

Below is a sample dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('Juan', 'Alice', 'Tim', 'Joe'),
                 zipc = c('11374', '11374', '11379', 'A145'))
```

I need an state and county column for my dataframe.

```
   name  zipc
1  Juan 11374
2 Alice 11374
3   Tim 11379
4   Joe  A145
```

Comment: Is `A145` a valid zipcode?

Comment: No it is not. In my real data there are some people with incorrect zip codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`zipcodeR` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zipcodeR/vignettes/zipcodeR.html) it can be done as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zipcodeR)

zip_code_db %>% 
  select(zipcode, state, county) %>% 
  right_join(df, by = c("zipcode"="zipc"), multiple = "all")

  zipcode state        county  name
1   11374    NY Queens County  Juan
2   11374    NY Queens County Alice
3   11379    NY Queens County   Tim
4    A145  <NA>          <NA>   Joe
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed. I just got an warning message :Warning message:
In right_join(., vis2, by = c(zipcode = "zip2")) :
  Each row in `x` is expected to match at most 1 row in `y`.
ℹ Row 129 of `x` matches multiple rows.
ℹ If multiple matches are expected, set `multiple = "all"` to silence this warning." but the result was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reverse_zipcode function doesn't return a value, even `NA`, when it can't find the zip code in the `zip_code_db` data frame included with the `zipcodeR` package. The example below checks whether the zip code "looks" correct and otherwise returns `NA`:

```
library(zipcodeR)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
data.frame(name = c('Juan', 'Alice', 'Tim', 'Joe'),
                 zipc = c('11374', '11374', '11379', 'A145')) %>%
  mutate(test2 = map_chr(zipc,
                         ~ ifelse(str_length(.) == 5 & !is.na(as.numeric(.)),
                                  zipcodeR::reverse_zipcode(.)$state,NA)))
```

Comment: This is good (it's how I thought of doing it) but it is not as good as @TarJae's accepted answer because it would get hung up on all-numeric but invalid zip codes (e.g., does zipcode 99999 exist?)

Comment: Based on how the `reverse_zipcode` function works, it would return `NA` if given zipcode 99999. I was slightly incorrect when I said that the function doesn't return anything if it can't find the zipcode in its data set -- it doesn't return anything if it deems the zipcode "invalid" as is the case with "A145."